# How to get Visible/ In-Visible legend elements in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can we get all the legend elements in the series that are visible when we click on any of the legend elements..

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
         legendItemClick: function(event) {
                var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                        }
            }
        }
    }
```

the above code gives us the current clicked element , but i need all the elements with the current element that are visible or invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
legendItemClick: function(event) {
                            var series = this.chart.series;
                            var seriesIndex = this.index;
                            var thisSeries=this.name;
                            var invisib=[];
                            invisib.push(thisSeries);

                            var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

                            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
                                    if(series[i].visible==false){
                                        invisib.push(series[i].name);
                                    }
                            }

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/5H2MZ/

```
legendItemClick: function (event) {

                    var chart = this.chart,
                        index = this.index;

                    $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){


                        if((serie.visible) && (serie.index != index))
                        {
                            alert('Serie: ' + serie.name + ' status visible');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('Serie: ' + serie.name + ' status hidden');
                        }    


                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all the series, and check the `visible` property of each one.